# Google App Engine for long running but low CPU tasks, or long-polling?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

App Engine has been great for requests that process quickly with no external API calls to databases or caches or third-party resources, but we've found that introducing any sort of "longer running" component or external latency (for example in a HTTP POST operation that runs asynchronously in the background and might take a second or two to process a few more intense database queries... totally invisible and OK from a UX perspective on the client-side because it's asynchronous but expensive to App Engine billing since it's long running) ... the "instance hours" compound and drive costs up considerably.

These sorts of expense inducing situations where a request is literally just waiting for a response from an external resource and requiring almost zero CPU during their idling **seem** avoidable, but I'm not sure if it's avoidable with App Engine.

It's almost like a "long poll" where the response might be left open but doing nothing.

Is there a way to do this on App Engine without just paying an insane amount for instance hours, or would we be better off moving to Compute Engine or EC2? Does it scale automatically based on CPU load, or is it based solely on open and perhaps inactive requests in total count? — `threadsafe` is indeed enabled.

Answer (score 4):

There are really two ways to go about this one (top of mind).

## Use Task Queues!

If the work doesn't need to be exactly at the same time of the request, this is exactly what [task queues] in App Engine are for.  They allow you to put a job on a queue, and have another module pick up the work.  They're kind of great because you can separately scale your front end and back end processes.

If that doesn't work....

## Use App Engine Flexible

Under the hood [App Engine Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/) is just running GCE instances.  The cost structure is entirely different, since you persistently have a VM running in the background serving your requests.

Hope this helps!

Comment: App Engine Flexible might work. We're already using task queues but some of these things need a front-end response.

Answer (score 0):

What you're really worried about here is how App Engine [scales](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/an-overview-of-app-engine#scaling_types_and_instance_classes) your instances. Because many of your requests require few resources, your app might be able to handle many more concurrent requests on a single instance than normal. You can look into parameters that shape scaling [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref#scaling_elements). Of particular interest:

> **max_concurrent_requests** The number of concurrent requests an automatic scaling instance can accept before the scheduler spawns a new instance (Default: 8, Maximum: 80).

There is a danger here, where an instance may fill up with non-long-polling requests and become overburdened. To prevent that, you could isolate your long-polling requests into their own [service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/an-overview-of-app-engine#services_the_building_blocks_of_app_engine) and set its scaling parameters separately from the rest of your app.